# Getting UnicodeDecodeError loading JSON file containing Chinese

Tags: python

I am trying to load a json file. The content of the file is in Chinese language. I am getting `UnicodeDecodeError:utf-8`. Is there any way to use try-except without losing all the content from the file?

```
def load_from_json(fin):
    datas = []
    for line in fin:
        data = json.loads(line)
        datas.append(data)
    return datas
```

Screenshot of the error

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us where you got this data? If you have no idea what the encoding might be, give `chardet` a try on the file contents.

Answer (score 1):

This may potentially be an issue with character encodings. There is a library called ftfy (Fixed That For You) which may be able to autodetect and auto-fix your character encodings:

- https://pypi.org/project/ftfy/

Answer (score 0):

It does look like the file might not actually be utf8, so that is indeed a good place to start, as per the other answer. However, to answer your actual question,

> Is there any way to use try-except without losing all the content from the file?

yes, there are two ways: one is that as well as setting `encoding="utf8"`, set `errors="replace"`. Then you'll get a Replacement Character U+FFFD (�) and things will continue as they were. You then try/except the json load and go from there. This is probably the simplest, but also not a very good solution for a long-term thing.

A better way would be to instead open the file in binary mode and do the decoding line by line, something like perhaps

```py
def load_from_json(fin):
    datas = []
    for i, line in enumerate(fin):
        try:
            data = json.loads(line.decode("utf8"))
        except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
            print(f"line {i}, {line!r}: {e}", file=sys.stderr)
        else:
            datas.append(data)
    return datas
```

Comment: in what way? (and, did you check the file's encoding?)